# empty or null field check with postgres query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to check two condition with case in posgtres query, in my table one field may have two values either will be empty or will be single quote('') so i tried this query but it didn't execute

```
CASE WHEN (items.item_code is NULL OR items.item_code = '') THEN
items.name::text ELSE items.item_code::text END as item_code
```

Error like:

> PG::Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...HEN
>   (items.item_code is NULL OR items.item_code = ) THEN ite..

Comment: "Empty or single quote" , do you mean `NULL` or empty string? because single quote is a whole different thing.

Comment: "It didn't execute"; what's the error?

Comment: Error like PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...HEN (items.item_code is NULL OR items.item_code = ) THEN ite...

Comment: you probabky gave php statement with single quotes - right?..

Comment: same like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800119/postgresql-case-end-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: Also that field value will be item_code: '' or item_code:

Comment: The SQL statement (well, the part you've shown us anyway) is syntactically correct. The problem probably lies with how you're calling it from rails.

Comment: if you change to this: `CASE WHEN coalesce(length(items.item_code),0) + length(items.item_code) THEN
items.name::text ELSE items.item_code::text END as item_code` error is gone?..

Comment: I am calling with scope in rails @Marth

Comment: That didn't work @VaoTsun, got error PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type integer

Comment: then it was quotes in your ruby - check out sql in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have problem with quotes in ruby, not in sql statement.
try changing to:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (coalesce(length(items.item_code),0) + length(items.item_code)) < 1
  THEN items.name::text ELSE items.item_code::text 
END as item_code
```

the code above does same condition check as yours, buta voids using quotes. I suppose your could should be smth like:

```
CASE WHEN (items.item_code is NULL OR items.item_code = \'\') THEN
items.name::text ELSE items.item_code::text END as item_code
```

Comment: That second one works fine, that was the quotes issue, thanks